# Can PHP's constants initialized by define() be accessed by different users

Tags: php, security

Can PHP's constants intialized by define() be accessed by different users in the system?

I seem to keep getting these confused with environment variables.

For example, if the user "www-data" executes define("password", "secure") and then as another I execute echo constant("password"); will he see the defined password or will it only be accessible to the user "www-data"

Comment: Constants are defined in your code, which runs threaded for each individual __request__; so constants defined in one __thread__ aren't automatically defined in another __thread__. They won't even be defined for another request by the same client unless you persist them in some way (e.g. in session)

Comment: Ah right, but if a attacker is able to inject code into the running request, he can grab the data right?

Comment: Each request runs entirely independently of every other request; your webserver ensures that; the only person that can inject code into an individual request, is the person who has initiated that request (ie the client)..... while you still have to protect against code injection, it doesn't allow that request to see the data being used by other requests

Comment: But isn't the define function itself a global constant loaded at the start of the application bootstrapping process? If thats initialized at the start of the build, and I inject code under the same user to which the define method was run, I have a entry point to view these defined constants right?

Comment: Every request runs completely independently of every other request.... that's lesson one. Lesson two, every request starts, runs and terminates, and all data (variables constants, etc) used in handling that request is then forgotten unless you deliberately persist it. define simply makes the value accessible from anywhere within that request, not across other requests

Comment: @SriramVenkatesh PHP constants are only available during the runtime and *after* the declaration with `define`. However, if an attacker is able to inject code into a PHP runtime (e. g., via some file inclusion vulnerability), the code has the same permissions as your code, which includes OS permissions on reading/writing/executing files on the server. So even if the constants is not available, an attacker may simply read the PHP file containing the constant declaration.

Comment: Oh right. So even if the attacker do not have direct access to the defined constant, the configuration containing all the prevalent informations is leaked and accessible. Cool Thanks!

Comment: I am happy to give either one of you the answers here